# How to test callback with Jasmine in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, callback, jasmine

I'm trying to test onclose callback of SignalR HubConnection but I can't find how to trigger the onclose callback.

This is what I want to test:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CloseConnectionHandlerService {
  constructor(
    private signalRService: SignalRService) {
  }

  public initialize(): void {
    this.signalRService.hubConnection?.onclose((error: any) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I'm trying with the following code:

```
describe('CloseConnectionHandlerService', () => {
  let service: CloseConnectionHandlerService;
  let signalRServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<SignalRService>;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    signalRServiceSpy = {
      ...jasmine.createSpyObj('SignalRService', ['']),
    } as jasmine.SpyObj<SignalRService>;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {provide: SignalRService, useValue: signalRServiceSpy},
      ]
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(CloseConnectionHandlerService);
  });
  
  describe('#initialize', () => {
    it('should log error to the console', () => {
      // Arrange
      spyOn(console, 'error');

      const hubConnectionStartSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj(HubConnection, ['onclose']);
      hubConnectionStartSpy.onclose.and.callFake(() => 'Error!');
      signalRServiceSpy.hubConnection = hubConnectionStartSpy

      // Act
      service.initialize();

      // Assert
      expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this I get the error that the console.error has not been called. Does anyone have an idea how I can test this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.signalRService.hubConnection?.onclose()` method accept a callback parameter. So the fake implementation created by the `.callFake()` method will override the original implementation and you can receive the original callback function in the test case. Then, invoke it with fake error manually.

E.g.

```
const hubConnectionStartSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HubConnection', ['onclose']);

hubConnectionStartSpy.onclose.and.callFake((callback) =>
  callback('Error!'); // You will get the original callback here, invoke it with fake error.
);
```